# Including Qt libraries in Dev-C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt4, dev-c++

All I want to know is how to import the Qt libraries in Dev-C++ so it will provide the same functionality as QT Creator 2.7.0. I know how to add 'include' and 'libraries' folders in Dev-C++ compiler options.

However the question is: where do I get those libraries from so that Dev-C++ can provide exactly same functionality as Qt Creator 2.7.0?.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are no libraries on Qt website for Dev-C++, so does it permanently means that there is no way to do that ?. One more question is: Does it's possible to use Qt libs with C++/CLI. I heard that Dev-C++ doesn't support C++/CLI

Comment: Dev-C++ **WON'T** provide the same functionality as QT Creator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dev-C++ is an IDE, not a compiler in itself. You can download the version with MinGW from [the Orwell site](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.ch/). Please don't use the older Bloodshed versions of Dev-C++.

The MinGW version is 4.7.*, which you can also download precompiled binaries for from http://qt-project.org/downloads. That should allow you to use Qt within Dev-C++.

That said, this does not provide you with the same integrated functionalities as Qt Creator does. You will just be able to write Qt code you can compile and run. It does not provide you with some of the more advanced design functionalities, though you could use the external designer. With that in mind, you might as well go for Qt Creator anyway.